# Space between elements of the indicator

Tags: android, android-viewpager, viewpagerindicator

How to increase/reduce space between elements of the indicator in `ViewPagerIndicator`?

Answer (score 9):

I have used `CirclePageIndicator`. I was able to make more space between two indicator by the step:

1. Open the source code of `CirclePageIndicator` and find the variable `mRadius`
2. At the line number around 235, you will find a line like below:

   ```
   final float threeRadius = mRadius * (some value here)
   ```
3. Change this some value, and play with it. I used `5` for my case, it gave me a good result.

Hope it solved your problem.

Answer (score 2):

There's no documented way to do this without some digging in.

I think @Md_Omar's answer is wrong as this increases the size of the indicator but not their separating distance.

And you could just use app:radius="5dp" instead if thats what you wanted.

See sample here

https://github.com/JakeWharton/ViewPagerIndicator/blob/master/sample/res/layout/themed_circles.xml

Answer (score 1):

You can set space by LayoutParams:

```
int numOfIndicators = 5;
int space = 20;

tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(myViewPager, true);
ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams params = 
         (ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams)tabLayout.getLayoutParams();//ConstraintLayout is my layout manager
params.width = numOfIndicators * space;
tabLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
```

(I used tabLayout with ViewPager as in this example: 
[Android ViewPager with bottom dots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20586619/android-viewpager-with-bottom-dots))

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a vector drawable, you can fiddle with the viewportWidth and viewportHeight to create spacing between TabLayout indicators if using the dots style.